# What is alternative of "TransparentNetworkIPResolution" in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have used "**TransparentNetworkIPResolution**" this keyword in ASP.NET MVC
in SQL Connection string.
My code as below

```
<add name="LocalString" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=LocalDBName;User ID=User;Password=****;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is giving me an error ASP.NET CORE 
error message **"Keyword doesn't support"**.

So can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you even need that keyword? It affects the connection attempt in a very specific way, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-transparent-network-ip-resolution

Answer (score 1):

Focus on new SqlClient features an improvements is moving to the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package

Please see https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/99

Github repo for SqlClient package is: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient

To reflect the current state of the API, here is a list of classes, enums and members that exists in .NET Framework on System.Data.SqlClient and that are missing in .NET Core's version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient:

```
Class SqlDataSourceEnumerator       
Class SqlAuthenticationInitializer      
Class SqlAuthenticationParameters       
Class SqlAuthenticationProvider     
Class SqlAuthenticationToken        
Class SqlClientLogger       
Class SQLDebugging       
Enum    SqlAuthenticationMethod 

Property    SqlBulkCopyOptions  AllowEncryptedValueModifications    
Property    SqlCommand  NotificationAutoEnlist  
Property    SqlConnectionStringBuilder  AsynchronousProcessing  
Property    SqlConnectionStringBuilder  Authentication  
Property    SqlConnectionStringBuilder  NetworkLibrary  
Property    SqlConnectionStringBuilder  TransparentNetworkIPResolution  
Property    SqlParameterCollection  IsSynchonized
```